# View of users-profile who had flagged me "subscribe"

Tags: views, flags

Using Drupal7 [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) 3 and [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) 3, I have been able to display users-profile I have flagged "subscribe" but no luck to display users-profiles that flagged me "subscribe".

Below is what I currently have but the result is still displaying users that the given url has flagged.

I used filter"user ID from url" and for relationships, I used "flags:subscribe(by any user) and checked/unchecked include only flagged content.

Please help. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cracked it!

1. **First add relationship**

   - Flags:User's flaggings

     - Check Include only users who have flagged content.
     - Pick your flag type (in my case "subscribe")
2. **Second add relationship**

   - Flags:User

     - relationship remains the same(user flagged content).
3. **Third add Contextual filters**

   - Flags:Entity ID

     - relationship remains the same(user flagged content)
     - provide default value (User ID from URL)
     - specify validation criteria (validator-user) in my case i have usernames (Allow both numeric UIDs and string usernames)
4. **Fourth add filter criteria**

   - Flags:User uid

     - relationship remains the same(user flagged content).
     - operator(tick "Is not empty (NOT NULL)") do not insert a username.

Save your view.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Create view with type "User"
2. Add Relationships "Flags: User's flaggings". Choose your flag name and set checkbox "Include only users who have flagged content."
3. Add Contextual filter "Flags: Entity ID". Choose in the filter settings "Provide default value" -> "User ID from URL"

Comment: under "flags:Entity ID, should I add the basic validation as user and criteria as id and usernames because i have id's as usernames?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you named your flag `subscribe`. Create a view of type `USERS`, Add the `USER` as Fields and In the Relationships add

```
Flags: subscribe (by current user)
```

Then the users subscribed will be shown. I used this method to follow users like what Instagram does. I mean your configuration should be like this (Instead of Follow select your flag):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still get the users flagged by the current user and not the users that has flagged the current user.

Comment: Take a screnshot if your view and place it in the question